# Insert records into a table based on value of a record in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a quotation system using Microsoft Access 2013.

Currently, my main issue to trying to write a query that selects all records from a table (itemquote) that have a certain quoteID matching the quoteID coming from another table (currentquote), and then inserts the results into a new table (quoteditems).

Here is a basic example of the tables:

**ItemQuote**

```
UniqueID  ItemID  QuoteID BuyPrice SellPrice
1         1       1       10.00    11.00
2         8       2       07.00    14.00
3         4       5       01.12    03.00
```

**CurrentQuote**

```
CurrentQuoteID
1
```

My current attempt at writing the query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblQuotedItems
SELECT *
FROM tblQuoteAsBuiltAndLabelling
INNER JOIN tblCurrentQuote
ON tblQuoteAsBuiltAndLabelling.QuoteID = tblCurrentQuote.CurrentQuoteID;
```

The resulting error message is "The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'CurrentQuoteID'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operation again." (Error 3127)

What should I do to my query to make it achieve the desired result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: tblQuotedItems tables should have same column as select query otherwise specify the specific columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be because your `tblQuotedItems` does not have the same number of column what your `Select Query` Returns.

So to resolve this, You can specified individual columns in INSERT Statement, and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can not specify column names in the `insert` if the columns in the `select` are in the same order as in the table definition.  Possibly, the columns in the current quote might be the same.  If so, this might work:

```
INSERT INTO tblQuotedItems
    SELECT tblCurrentQuote.*
    FROM tblQuoteAsBuiltAndLabelling INNER JOIN
         tblCurrentQuote
         ON tblQuoteAsBuiltAndLabelling.QuoteID = tblCurrentQuote.CurrentQuoteID;
```

However, I strongly recommend that you include column names explicitly when you do inserts:

```
INSERT INTO tblQuotedItems(col1, col2, . . .)
    SELECT col1, col2, . . .
    FROM tblQuoteAsBuiltAndLabelling INNER JOIN
         tblCurrentQuote
         ON tblQuoteAsBuiltAndLabelling.QuoteID = tblCurrentQuote.CurrentQuoteID;
```